# server.servlet.context-path not working (wtf)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

My application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController {

    @GetMapping({ "/v1.0" })
    public ResponseEntity<List<Post>> getPosts(@RequestParam Optional<String> maxId) {
        List<Post> posts = Arrays.asList(
                new Post(new ObjectId().toString(), "Test status 1", LocalDateTime.now()),
                new Post(new ObjectId().toString(), "Test status 2", LocalDateTime.now()),
                new Post(new ObjectId().toString(), "Test status 3", LocalDateTime.now()),
                new Post(new ObjectId().toString(), "Test status 4", LocalDateTime.now()),
                new Post(new ObjectId().toString(), "Test status 5", LocalDateTime.now()),
                new Post(new ObjectId().toString(), "Test status 6", LocalDateTime.now()),
                new Post(new ObjectId().toString(), "Test status 7", LocalDateTime.now()),
                new Post(new ObjectId().toString(), "Test status 8", LocalDateTime.now()),
                new Post(new ObjectId().toString(), "Test status 9", LocalDateTime.now()),
                new Post(new ObjectId().toString(), "Test status 10", LocalDateTime.now())
        );
        return ResponseEntity.ok(posts);
    }

}
```

This uri gives me a result in Postman:

```
localhost:8080/posts/v1.0
```

Whereas this one does not:

```
localhost:8080/api/posts/v1.0
```

Doesn't make any sense.

Version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</parent>
```

Note: application.properties gets properly read, I can change the port number at will.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-context-path/

Comment: Is it possible that you are overriding the context-path somewhere with a configuration that is in your class path?

Comment: @DavidBrossard Epic 404? :-)

Comment: @DavidBrossard - That Baeldung link doesn't work for me, but I found a very similar one that I assume is what you wanted to direct us to:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path - I looked this over, and all it seems to do is confirm that the OP is doing the right thing.

Comment: Strange.  All I can think of is what @RandyCasburn suggests.  You might want to confirm what the final value of that property is by injecting it somewhere or looking it up in the Spring Environment.   That would narrow it down to if the property is not being set to what you think it is, or if it has the right value and that value is somehow not having the expected effect.

Comment: @Steve I found the problem, I'll add an answer for future reference.

Comment: @html_programmer - Coolio!

Comment: I have literally no idea what happened to my copy paste there but you found the right article and if anything it confirms that you're doing the right thing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I'm currently writing is boilerplate (this is why I hadn't implemented Webflux yet, simply to get a basic REST api working), but I have added the Maven Webflux package because I want a reactive api:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

In which case the following property is needed instead:

```
spring.webflux.base-path=/api
```

Comment: I thought of this. But doesn't the Controller you show in your question mean you're not using WebFlux?  Maybe that's what you mean by "currently writing boilerplate".  I'm a bit confused.  Maybe you could clarify, but the answer in the end is clear.  Thanks for posting it.

Comment: @Steve You're correct in your assumption that this is what I meant with boilerplate. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to have dynamic and changable prefix for your uri, you could use custom variables in your properties file and use them as prefix of your mapping by ${}

Comment: I don't see that the OP said anything about desiring a dynamic prefix.  The issue here is that a static prefix is being set but seemingly ignored.  (PS: I'm not the downvoter...yet)

Comment: its your decision that downvote, I tried to say solution that worked for me

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but indeed I prefer using built-in properties where I can to reduce boilerplate.